# meteor How can I set the ROOT_URL for IOS

Tags: cordova, meteor

I try to set up `ROOT_URL` to build my IOS app 
so when I passed this:

```
meteor run ios --mobile-server https://example.org/folder/
```

the `ROOT_URL` is set as https://www.example.org only. It seems cordova do not consider the rest of the url.

How can I set `ROOT_URL` properly?

Comment: Here is the result in the html header

{"meteorRelease":"METEOR@1.4.2.1","ROOT_URL":"https://www.example.org/","ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"","DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL":"https://www.example.org/","autoupdateVersionCordova":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","appId":"xxxxxxxxx","meteorEnv":{"NODE_ENV":"development","TEST_METADATA":"{}"}}"

Comment: It's only to tell the name of the server (and the protocol). IOS apps don't really have a path, although your webapp will do routing internally

Comment: If i force it to the path+folder in xcode it works, but I can not use it for a production...

Comment: Any body can help ?  Up ??

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue and this is what I ended up doing:

1. After building the project, navigate to the newly compiled project and open ios/project/www/application/index.html
2. In the file, locate the **meteor_runtime_config** variable. This is where you can edit the ROOT_URL. It can be tedious modifying this manually, so instead copy everything inside the quotes and paste it in a URL decoder tool such as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/.
3. Modify both the ROOT_URL and also the DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL to your required values.
4. Then re-encode the string and paste it back into index.html
5. Run/export the XCode project as normal.

This is definitely a workaround and I was hoping to find something better. The server bundle handles subdirectories in the ROOT_URL just fine, so hopefully Meteor can fix this.